# How do I change getElementById 2nd time around?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, overlapping

I am creating a multiple choice question that requires the user to click an answer (radio button). If the user clicks the check answer button before selecting an answer, he is prompted to select an answer. This works fine. However, if the user then selects a wrong answer and clicks the check answer button, the appropriate response is displayed over the previous prompt. I tried changing the getElementById for the prompt to display "", but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (document.Questions.Q_ans[i].checked == false) {
        document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML = "Select answer before continuing.";
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('answer_b').checked || document.getElementById('answer_c').checked) {
    document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML = incorrect;
    document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: What's `document.Questions`? And you really need to use `var i` to avoid making it a global.

Comment: Shouldn't `incorrect` be a string?

Answer (score 0):

This line fails since `incorrect` should either be defined as a variable or it should be wrapped in quotes:

```
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML = "incorrect"; // <-- Should be in quotes
```

So your script never executes the line after.

Comment: incorrect is a variable that is declared at the beginning of the coding.

Comment: That's fine, but it is inconsistent with the way you handle the message in the first case. Maybe a comment in your question clarifying that would be helpful since it sent everyone down the wrong path :)

Answer (score 0):

As @brian buck said, your script doesn't get executed after the `incorrect` statement which should be a defined variable or wrapped in quotes (to be executed as a string). Your script silently fails and basically does nothing (at least, nothing you can see).

A few things here I would also recommend:

- Make sure to use `var i` in your loop to avoid scope error
- Your first loop check seems a bit odd to me: for every (assumed) possible answer not checked, you display the same error. It is not critical, but your script does something each time instead of once. You could have, let's say, a boolean that you toggle when you discover that an answer has been checked somewhere, and assign your error statement at the end depending on the value of this boolean. However, my "naked" JS is a bit rusty for that situation, and I am totally sure that there are better solutions to it!
- As it appears you haven't been notified of the script failure, I don't think you use any debugger. If you are doing JS in a web browser, you could use the embedded consoles. Otherwise, there are plenty of tools taht could help you a lot. I remember losing my hair when starting to play with JS, because it got silent everytime it wasn't happy...

Comment: Not quite sure about your first comment, "Make sure to use var i in your loop to avoid scope error". I declare var i; in the line before the for loop starts. What I am trying to do with the loop is check all of the radio buttons and see if any were checked. If none were checked, I want to let the user know they need to check one. If the wrong answer is selected, I want to let them know it is incorrect. If the right answer is selected, I want them to know it is correct. Each response is based on the user clicking the score button.I'm just using HTML-Kit 292 that appears to give script errors.

Comment: I think I got what you are trying to achieve. Without trying to patronize you at all, the algorithm seems a bit odd to me: you are using radio buttons, so if there is ever more than one answer choice, the `if` in your first loop will always be evaluated at true at some point (an unchecked choice will always exist), making your loop basically useless. I am sure there are plenty of efficient (and well-documented across the web) ways to check empty values in radio buttons.

Comment: About my first comment, it's just that we generally use `for (var i = 0; i < [...]; i++)`. That way, `i` won't be available outside of your loop. And for your initial problem, I don't think there is a problem with this snippet - assuming the `incorrect` variable is correctly defined and in the proper scope.

Comment: Jeremie, thank you for your comments. I fixed the code by removing the for loop and replacing it with && logical operators, in addition to adding return; to the end of the first if statement.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Please do not forget to vote for the best results and to accept the answer that suited your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery, replace all the "document.getElementById('yourId')" for "$('#yourid')"
and you must have initialized a `var len` for your loop.

js:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (document.Questions.Q_ans[i].checked == false) {
        $("#reply_b").innerHTML = "Select answer before continuing.";
    }
}

if ($('#answer_b').checked || $('#answer_c').checked) {

    $("#reply_a").innerHTML = incorrect;
    $("#reply_b").innerHTML = "";      
}
```